# Doesn't rust infer lifetimes of function parameters without explicitly specifying them?

Tags: function, rust, lifetime

```
pub(crate) fn foo<'a, 'b>(param1: &'a str, param2: &'b str) -> &'b str {
    if param2.starts_with(param1) {
        &s[param1.len()..]
    } else {
        panic!("expected {}", param1);
    }
}

pub(crate) fn foo<'b>(param1: &str, param2: &'b str) -> &'b str {
    if param2.starts_with(param1) {
        &s[param1.len()..]
    } else {
        panic!("expected {}", param1);
    }
}
```

Pardon me for the ultra-noob question here, but are these functions different? Isn't it already inferred that the lifetime would be different for both parameters without explicitly specifying it? If they're the same, is there any benefit to specifying them like this, or is this a common format everybody follows?

Comment: It is, declaring the lifetime is redundant.

Comment: See also: [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html)

Comment: I don't know any benefit besides the opinionated readability gain. And while personally I prefer to elide lifetimes wherever possible, I don't think there is a rule everybody follows.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for clarifying this!

Comment: In simple cases like this one, the compiler's lifetime inference is often sufficient and explicit annotations may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think it this way: when a reference doesn't have a lifetime, it has his own

you know, before in rust, every reference had a lifetime, and sometimes you did a lifetime for every reference, but people realized it would be good to add implicit lifetimes, where every reference by default has his own lifetime and developer doesn't even needs to think about it, which makes the work easier, lifetimes still exists because in much cases you need to specify them

so yeah, these functions are the same